# migrate some data results to another jsp page

Tags: javascript, java, html, forms, jsp

So, i want to know how can i set another jsp file . I already have (index.jsp) only. 
. What i would like to do is migrate data from index.jsp file to newfile.jsp like "static" where i can change background etc because when i click on submit he redirects me to another page that i haven't physically. 
  i have a form like this:

```
 <form method="get" action ="${pageContext.request.contextPath }/webserverlet?">

 name:   <input type = "text"  name = "name" placeholder = "name" value="${name}" id="name"><br><br>

 <input value="Submit" type="submit" id="submit" >
```

my file webserverlet.java:

```
String name=request.getParameter("name");
```

I'm sorry but i'm new  in java serverlet.